# jquery cycle fade image position center

Tags: jquery, image, cycle, fade

I am using the jQuery Cycle plugin to fade images in and out. I've built it on a CMS to crop the images, etc. If I have a really tall image I want the image to be positioned in the center. The plugin uses position:absoulte; while fading the images in and out. I've tried editing the plugin with the left:50%; width:half of width; but I can't really get it to work. Are there any other plugins I can use? or maybe a way around this?

If you firebug you can see how the plugin styles the image with position:absolute;

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html

Comment: A test page will be helpful here.

Comment: a link to plugin and you code will be helpful to you

Comment: @Wayen Khan @expermientX Added

Answer (score 3):

Try setting margin for each of the images like this:

```
var mainW= jQuery('.slideshow').width();
jQuery('.slideshow img').each(function(){
    var imgW = jQuery(this).width();
    var margL=0-(imgW-mainW)/2;
    jQuery(this).css('marginLeft',margL);
});
```

This assumes div.slideshow is holding your images.
Make sure that you define, e.g. *width: 250px;* in css for it!